# How to keep Windows Service running after computer is restarted?

Tags: c#, windows-services, service-broker, sqldependency

I have this Windows Service (using `SqlDependency`) that sends me an e-mail everytime it is started and everytime a new row is inserted on my Sales table (the database has `Service Broker` enabled).
I also write a log file to register when the service is started, the data is inserted to the table, if the e-mail was successfully sent and when the service is stoped.

- When I started the service manually, it worked just fine.
- Then I turned my PC off and on again and inserted data on my table
  in the database, but nothing happened (no e-mail sent and no
  register in my log file).
- I restarted the service manually and it worked fine again.
- Turned the PC off and on again and nothing heppened again.
- I made some research and changed the initialization type to Automatic
  and tried again. And nothing happened again.
- I changed the initialization type to Automatic Delayed and tried
  again. But it didn't work too, even 1 hour after I turned the PC on.
- Now I manually restarted the service and the log file registered that
  the service stoped and started, I received the email that the service
  started and, after I inserted data in my database table, both log
  register and email message worked just fine.

Everytime it didn't work, I checked the services manager in Windows and it was marked as "Running".

I don't know if I need to configure something different in my code or in my service properties.
Has anybody ever had this issue?

### ***EDIT***

I modified my service and included a timer, so every minute passed it writes the time in my log text file. After I restarted my PC, the log file continued to register the time every minute, but did not register the insert I made in my database table.

My guess is that the service might be losing the database connection when the PC is restarted, so the `SqlDependency` cannot detect the changes. Does it make any sense?

Comment: Not programming related. We have a separate site for database administration (dba.stackexchange.com)

Comment: Sorry, I thought there was something I had to change in my code for this to work. Thanks!

Comment: Log your service execution. If it is marked as running it should execute at least some sequence. Maybe service execution crashes in some part because some windows parts are not yet initialized. For example working network connection, database server is not yet started, etc.

Comment: @MichalZhradnkNono3551 I am currently making a log file (during code execution, it writes on a text file some messages that I determine). Is there another way to log it?

Comment: @Gabic There are plenty other ways but file logs should be enough to find problem. Maybe you should also check event viewer in windows for some information. But since your service did not crash and is still running you might not find what you are looking for.

Comment: @MichalZhradnkNono3551 I'm trying to work around it, by writing a batch script to stop and start the service when the user makes login, since the service simply won't work properly

Answer (score 3):

Your service depends on SQL Server, but your service is probably starting before SQL Server has been started, or finished starting. This may be causing your `SqlDependency` to fail.

You can mark your service as being dependent on SQL Server, which means:

- Windows won't attempt to start your service until SQL Server has started and is ready, and
- Starting your service will cause Windows to start SQL Server before it starts your service

This can be achieved on the command-line with the `sc` command (which will need to be run at an administrative command prompt). If your SQL Server instance is named `MSSQLSERVER` and your service is named `MyService` the command would look like this:

```
sc config MyService depend= MSSQLSERVER
```

*Note: The space after `=` and before `MSSQLSERVER` matters. The detailed syntax can be found on [learn.microsoft.com](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/sc-config).*

Once this command has run successfully, this is what you'll see when looking at the properties of your service in Control Panel > Administrative Tools > Services:

[image]

Comment: I did it and restarted the service, now it shows an error saying `Error 1075: the dependency service does not exist or has been marked for deletion`. Even after restarting the computer and trying to start the service, it shows the same error

Comment: Did you replace `MSSQLSERVER` with the name of the SQL Server windows service on your machine? The error you've received makes me suspect that you haven't..? Note that the name of the service will be displayed as 'Service name' on the 'General' tab for the properties of the SQL Server service in the Services control panel, don't assume that yours will be called MSSQLSERVER, particularly if you're using SQL Server Express edition

Comment: Yes, I changed it to my server name. The service is running on my machine, and the SqlServer is running on a SqlServer 2014 database server. Does it have any influence?

Comment: the command executed successfully, but when I open the service properties, it doesn't show SQL Server like yours, it's just empty

Comment: Display name and service name is not same, always. Discover what is running this at cmd line: sc query type= service > services.txt

Comment: @lsalamon yes, mine are different. I tried the command with the service name, and it executed successfully, but didn't show the dependecy in the properties. So I thought that I should use the display name and tried again, and then I got an error saying it didn't exist

Comment: Right, the command is only relevant if SQL Server and your service are running on the same machine, unfortunately you can't use it for cross-machine dependencies. Something else, other than the SQL Server service not being ready is causing your problem I'm afraid

Comment: @Rob I imagine there is something happening when I restart the PC that is interfering with the working of my service, but I can't figure out what it is. It is not stoped, but it doesn't work either.